# Best source for origins of expressions and idioms?

Tags: etymology, idioms, expressions, research

I'm often interested in the origins of English phrases, and I know that I can find answers by googling, and I can find *good* answers by asking here.

How can I find good answers myself? Are there any well-known, respected, and fairly comprehensive sources for origins of English expressions and idioms?

Answer (score 4):

A handy source online is The Phrase Finder:

http://www.phrases.org.uk/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006019653X) now at 16th edition.It is a bulky one -1326 pages

Answer (score 1):

Some other good online resources:

[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php) (often has phrases within entries for individual words)
[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tra2.htm)  (Michael Quinion's archive of well-researched articles)
[Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/index.php) (excellent discussion-based site with a focus on word and phrase origins)

and ditto to @Robusto's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/best-source-for-origins-of-expressions-and-idioms/23146#23146). . .([usually](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23161/5822))

Answer (score 0):

*[Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable](http://www.bartleby.com/81/)* is a good start for many expressions.  There are a couple of on-line versions; I've linked to the most searchable one I could find, but Google will show you others.

Comment: @Bogdan: that sounds plausible.  I'd certainly recommend getting a paper copy anyway.