# "Three time's a charm" vs "third time's a charm"?

Tags: proverbs

The most commonly used one is "third time's a charm". I googled it and couldn't find "three time's a charm" in usage. So is "three time's a charm" considered incorrect?

Comment: I've never heard 'three times a charm' and it seems like a confusion of the actual adage

Comment: Is it grammatically incorrect to say so?

Comment: As per your edit, yes: "three time's" is wrong. Anyway, the proverb is referring to the third (ordinal not cardinal) time something is done being the time it works

Comment: I believe that the proverbial usage is actually "Third time's *the* charm.".

Comment: It looks like a (to me, *non-standard*) mangling of [**third time lucky**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23161/). So I think this is a duplicate of that earlier ELU question.

Comment: ...note that even in AmE, the "lucky" version is still more common than "charm" (in BrE the "charm" version is too uncommon to even show on [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Third+time%27s+the+charm%2CThird+time%27s+a+charm%2CThird+time+lucky&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThird%20time%20%27s%20the%20charm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThird%20time%20%27s%20a%20charm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThird%20time%20lucky%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Interesting. In my area of the US (NYC Metro), I don't think I've _ever_ heard "third time lucky" - always TTtC.

Comment: I think that generally, if you google for a variant of a well known phrase, and don't find many (or any) results, then no, it's not considered correct. This seems totally obvious to me.   It's like saying *"I know about the bird called Albatross.  I googled it and couldn't find "Ablatrsos" in usage.  Is "Ablatrsos" considered incorrect?"*

Comment: Interesting that no one has talked about what the apostrophe s might stand for in “Three time’s a charm”  and whether there’s an option that’s grammatically correct.  The only way I can get anything grammatical is without the apostrophe, and then it means it’s been lucky on three occasions and not “maybe if we try it again it’ll work”

Comment: Oh wait, if that's what i was going for then "three times a charm" is grammatically correct without the apostrophe?

Comment: @Jim The apostrophe is probably meant as a contraction of "three time is a charm", which just serves to highlight the wrongness of it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Yes, my point exactly.

Comment: You googled it and couldn't find it. QED.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct expression is:

> [***the third time is the charm***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20third%20time%20is%20the%20charm)
>   US
>   —used to say that two efforts at something have already failed but perhaps the third will be successful

You will also find [***third time's the charm***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/third+time%27s+the+charm) and [***third time's a charm***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third_time%27s_a_charm) versions of the same.

I've never heard ***three time's a charm*** and I believe the inability to find any significant evidence of its usage is indicative.

---

**Note:**

According to [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/third-time-lucky.html):

> the American expression 'third time's a charm' [...] may be an [*sic*] variant of the earlier 'third time lucky' or it may have arisen independently in the USA.

Comment: Probably because "three times a charm" doesn't make sense.  Maybe they'd been listening to The Commodores - "You're once...twice...three times a lady..."

Comment: @MaxWilliams I think they meant "three times is a/the charm". Which does make sense, but isn't used either (or at least not enough to appear on Ngram viewer).